# how to store in array in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32

```
A[k++] = A[k] + A[k]
# i-> $s0, k-> $s1 , base of A[] ->$s2
```

i tried the following but can't figure out how to store back in array A[k++]....

```
sll $t0 , $s1 , 2
add $t0 , $t0 , $s2
lw $t1, 0($t0)
add $s1, $t1 , $t1 # i added A[k] + A[k]
```

Comment: How about using `sw` to *store* it since you use `lw` to *load* it, or is there some other problem?

Comment: # shift left logical 

    sll $t1 , $s1 , 2

# add 1

    addi $t1 , $t1 , 1

# now add with the base

    add $t1, $t1 , $s2

# finally store back in array

    sw $s1 , 0($t1) 

will it work ?

Comment: You already have the address in $t0, no need to calculate it again. Just store.

Comment: the element memory location are calculated as follow: array variable base address + 4bytes index in case you have an array with or words... otherwise you should index with the element size, for string will be byte.

Answer (score 1):

In order to iterate throught arrays in MIPS, you need to add 4 bytes for each position of the array. Example:

```
.data
  myArray: .store 12 # array with length of 3 (3 x 4 bytes)
.text
  li $t0, 0
  li $s0, 1
  sw $s0, myArray($t0) # myArray[0] = 1
  addi $t0, 4
  sw $s0, myArray($t0) # myArray[1] = 1
  addi $t0, 4
  sw $s0, myArray($t0) # myArray[2] = 1
```